# Регулярные выражения java - разделение строки по предложениям

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

коллеги

Мне на вход поступает строка, я должен разделить ее по предложениям и раскидать по ячейкам в экселе - сейчас я делаю это так `content.split("\\. ")`

Проблема заключается в том, что в тексте существуют уточнения - пояснения в скобках, внутри которых тоже есть точка, но не от конца предложения, а от сокращения слова

Как мне делить по предложениям, чтобы регулярное выражение не обращало внимания на точки между скобок?

Спасибо!

Comment: Может, так - `content.split("\\. (?![^()]*\\))")`

Comment: Это сработало! Супер!) 

Можете добавить это как ответ, чтобы я мог оценить?

Также, если можно, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что почитать, чтобы разобраться по теме?

Comment: Честно говоря, всё, что я знаю, я выучил на англоязычных сайтах: http://rexegg.com, http://regular-expressions.info и на англоязычном SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать блок предварительного просмотра вперёд для проверки, нет ли сразу после вашего шаблона 0 и более символов, отличных от круглых скобок, за которыми следует закрывающая скобка:

```
String[] results = content.split("\\. (?![^()]*\\))");
```

[Пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/1hTS2I/1)

**Подробности**

- `\.`  - точка и пробел
- `(?![^()]*\))` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд для проверки, нет ли сразу после вашего шаблона

  - `[^()]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от круглых скобок
  - `\)` - символ `)`.